# Netbiter IOX-8AIV Checksum Error in Repsonse Message - Modbus RS485 modscan

Tags: modbus, rs485, modbus-rtu-over-tcp

I have a testing environment for the modbus.  I have the Beckhoff CX5140 with EL4004. Then I have netbiter IOX-8AIV connect to EL4004.  Then from my laptop, I use type C to Serial modbus RTU RS485 to connect to netbiter.  when I run the Modscan 64 bit, it return Checksum Error in response Message.

[image]

Here is the setting
[image]

[image]

I try use another modscan software to scan and it return me some result but I not sure what the meaning of the return result.
in Beckhoff, I has force the 6v value to the netbiter but seem like nothing change on the return result.  In netbiter, I use input 1 & 2.

[image]

[image]

I'm totally new in this field and no any training before hands on for this job.

Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you are trying co make a Modbus RTU request to a [IOX-8AIV](https://www.netbiter.com/docs/default-source/netbiter-english/manuals/hms-hmsi-27-228.pdf?sfvrsn=f8c4c2d6_30) (what's connected to that is not really relevant). The values you are getting back should correspond to the voltage on the respective inputs.

Comment: @Brits Ya, I'm trying to get a value from the NetBiter IOX-8AIV.  In Beckhoff, I try to force the value to 7V or 10V but the return value was the same.

Comment: OK, the values do look wrong. The reading should be 0–4095; but the spec does not specifically state that the high bits will be 0. I would also expect flags to be set in 30010 due to the open circuits. Are the readings all 0 when you have nothing connected?